# How can I build an adjusted coffin?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, xcoffins

I would like to put several lines of text stacked vertically inside a coffin, and have the coffin be the tightest rectangle containing them.  One way to get a coffin containing those lines is to use `\SetVerticalCoffin` with an explicit width argument, but this doesn't make a tight coffin.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\Text
\SetVerticalCoffin\Text{12em}{\noindent%
  email@address.com\\%
  My postal address,\\%
  99999, BC, Canada%
}
\TypesetCoffin\Text
\end{document}
```

Another way is to build separate horizontal coffins and join them with the correct alignment, but that doesn't take care of proper line skips (even with the `\strut` inserted).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\Tmp
\NewCoffin\Text
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Tmp{\strut email@address.com}
\JoinCoffins\Text[b,l]\Tmp[t,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Tmp{\strut My postal address,}
\JoinCoffins\Text[b,l]\Tmp[t,l]
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Tmp{\strut 99999, BC, Canada}
\JoinCoffins\Text[b,l]\Tmp[t,l]
\TypesetCoffin\Text
\end{document}
```

Neither approach is great.  How do I get the coffin I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. Nah, just kidding :)

Comment: use an `\halign` and coffin-ize the resulting vbox? or are you really asking for a coffin function in place of join that aligns on the specified poles but offsets to preserve baselineskip?

Comment: @Jubobs Sorry, I forgot to say 'Helllllo gentle folks!' before and 'Thanks a lot if you help me!!! I'm loooost!' after my question.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I guess the right approach would be to use a TeX's tables, but it's not clear to me how to get a coffin out of that without ever specifying a width.  Perhaps `\SetHorizontalCoffin\Text{\vbox{\halign{#\cr Foo\cr Bar\cr Baz\cr}}}`?  So I guess maybe I need a `\SetVerticalCoffin` variant which does not require a width argument (`\vbox` instead of `\vbox to ...`).

Comment: I hear that [not apologising to a mule](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8a5OcWIqgAI) is a good way to get a coffin. I'm not sure if it's the one you want, though.

Comment: Why not a `tabular`?

Comment: @egreg Because I was silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some ideas from my initial false attempts, I suggested using a `\Longstack` from the `stackengine` package.  Here, I just stick it inside the horizontal coffin.  The `[l]` optional argument left justifies the text in the stack.  The interline spacing can be altered with `\setstackgap{L}{length}`.  The `\fbox` demonstrates that it is the tightest coffin possible  (but if you wanted the stack to be strutted, `\strutlongstacks{T}` in the preamble will see to that).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcoffins}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\NewCoffin\Text
\SetHorizontalCoffin\Text{%
\Longstack[l]{email@address.com\\My postal address\\99999, BC, Canada}%
}
\fboxsep=0pt
\fbox{\TypesetCoffin\Text}
\end{document}
```

[image]

In comments to the OP, egreg had suggested using `tabular` as a means to achieve the goal, and the OP asked for a compare/contrast on the two ideas.  Indeed, one can take the macro line

```
\Longstack[l]{email@address.com\\My postal address\\99999, BC, Canada}%
```

and replace it with the environment

```
\begin{tabular}{l}
email@address.com\\My postal address\\99999, BC, Canada
\end{tabular}%
```

to achieve a similar result at the expense of a few extra keystrokes.  Both methods can control the inter-row spacing with settable parameters.  HOWEVER, there are differences in these two results.  The `tabular` result is padded both on the left/right as well as the top/bottom.  The left/right padding can be removed with the extra step of setting `\tabcolsep=0pt`.  I am not exactly sure how to remove the top/bottom padding off of a tabular, other than setting `\arraystretch` to `0`, but that, of course destroys the inter-row spacing, as well.  Perhaps someone can comment on how that part is done.

Those are the differences that pop out to me. I don't know if the baseline of the object stuffed into a coffin affects the coffin behavior.  However, both `tabular` and `stackengine` can control their respective baselines, so that shouldn't be an issue, per se.  If I knew more about coffins, there may be other things that come to mind.

Of course, `tabular` is built into LaTeX, whereas `stackengine` is an extra package.

Comment: Bruno means one of these http://river-valley.zeeba.tv/exhuming-coffins-from-the-last-century/

Comment: This does look like a good use case for the `stackengine` package.  For completeness, could you comment on the advantage/drawback of using `\Longstack[l]{...}` rather than `\begin{tabular}{l}...\end{tabular}`?  (Probably `\Longstack` is more efficient at least for small tables... but most definitely that does not matter since coffins are much slower.)

Comment: Thank you.  Accepted.  I think the `\Longstack` approach is most practical in this case.